Dot or Cross(Regarding Calculation of Gradients of matrices using chain rule)
Have been learning how to train neural networks a problem was encountered.Here in this code the confusion is how to understand when to do multiplication using '*' and when 'using np.dot()'
def loss_gradients(forward_info: Dict[str, ndarray], 
                   weights: Dict[str, ndarray]) -> Dict[str, ndarray]:
    '''
    Compute the partial derivatives of the loss with respect to each of the parameters in the neural network.
    '''    
    dLdP = -(forward_info['y'] - forward_info['P'])
    
    dPdM2 = np.ones_like(forward_info['M2'])

    dLdM2 = dLdP * dPdM2
  
    dPdB2 = np.ones_like(weights['B2'])

    dLdB2 = (dLdP * dPdB2).sum(axis=0)
    
    dM2dW2 = np.transpose(forward_info['O1'], (1, 0))
    
    dLdW2 = np.dot(dM2dW2, dLdP)

    dM2dO1 = np.transpose(weights['W2'], (1, 0)) 

    dLdO1 = np.dot(dLdM2, dM2dO1)
    
    dO1dN1 = sigmoid(forward_info['N1']) * (1- sigmoid(forward_info['N1']))
    
    dLdN1 = dLdO1 * dO1dN1
    
    dN1dB1 = np.ones_like(weights['B1'])
    
    dN1dM1 = np.ones_like(forward_info['M1'])
    
    dLdB1 = (dLdN1 * dN1dB1).sum(axis=0)
    
    dLdM1 = dLdN1 * dN1dM1
    
    dM1dW1 = np.transpose(forward_info['X'], (1, 0)) 

    dLdW1 = np.dot(dM1dW1, dLdM1)

    loss_gradients: Dict[str, ndarray] = {}
    loss_gradients['W2'] = dLdW2
    loss_gradients['B2'] = dLdB2.sum(axis=0)
    loss_gradients['W1'] = dLdW1
    loss_gradients['B1'] = dLdB1.sum(axis=0)
    
    return loss_gradients

The thought was that knowing when to use which is essential since the outputs differ

Please (re)read "how to post a good question" and [edit] your post accordingly. If you wrote this code yourself, then you should have some familiarity here already: which one do you think you should use, and when you do that, what happens that makes you think there might be a problem either in your assumption, or your code?

If you want to use element wise multiplication use * . Typically for gradients or activation functions
If you want Matrix Multiplication use np.dot or @. This is use for combining the gradients across several layers/ nodes.

Weerakon Thank You
